# Can not delete element fron JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an issue. I need to delete the element from JSON  as per key value using PHP but its having some problem. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$comment = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '', 'comment' => ''),array('day_id' => '2', 'comment' => 'hello'), array('day_id' => '3', 'comment' => 'vodka3'),array('day_id'=>'','comment'=>'')));
$arrComment = json_decode($comment, true);
$imgarr=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arrComment);$i++){
    if($arrComment[$i]['day_id']=='' && $arrComment[$i]['comment']==''){
        unset($arrComment[$i]);
    }
}
$arrComment=array_values($arrComment);
print_r($arrComment);
?>
```

Here when my multiple element key value is blank its not working. BUt if one single case its working. Here my need is if any of element `day_id and comment` is blank those element will remove from that json object and it will re-index again. Please help me.

Comment: It's **NOT** JSON, it's a PHP array.

Comment: @Rax Weber He just encode and decode it for better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing `unset($arrComment[$i]);` length of your array reduces. So, `count($arrComment)` is not **4** but **3**. That's why your last element is **not reached**. To avoid this - use `count()` before starting the loop:

```
$cou = count($arrComment);
for($i=0; $i<$cou; $i++){
    if($arrComment[$i]['day_id']=='' && $arrComment[$i]['comment']==''){
        unset($arrComment[$i]);
    }
}
```

Or use for example `array_filter`:

```
$arrComment = array_filter(
    $arrComment,
    function($v) { return $v['day_id']!='' && $v['comment']!=''; }
);
print_r($arrComment);
```